# old and proprietary java application crashes on multiple cores

Tags: linux, debian, java, crash, multi-core

I have to use StarTeam 2005 CrossPlatform Client on a recent debian system inside of a VM. This works fine, if the VM is configured to single-core. But if I configure multiple processors and/or multiple cores, the application freezes on startup showing only the splash-screen. No error trace is shown on the console.

Is there a workaround to get such applications up and running on a multi-core-environement? CUrrently, I've either have to reboot, if I want to check in or work with a single-core-setup. I use this VM for development and `make -j8` is more fun than just a plain `make` ;)

I tried to hack a call into the startup-script like `schedtool -a 0x1 -v -e java ...` (setting processor affinity to one) but with no success - same behaviour.

The same has happened on an older setup (older VM, older linux, same StarTeam) but I do not have the version numbers of those. Here is the setup of the current system:

- VMWare Workstation 9.0.3 build-1410761, guest additions installed
- Debian Wheezy (Linux cmd-vm 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux)
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
- launch-script: LAXUNIX.SH - LaunchAnywhere (tm) version 5.0
- StarTeam Cross Platform Client Build 7.0.0-133

Comment: Limiting the CPU is the only way you can fix this. Look around for other tools like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core.

Comment: Thats what I have tried with `schedtool`. The `taskset` from the question you mentioned fails also but interestingly, the splash screen of the application goes away - the java process is at 100% CPU load on both scenarios.

Comment: Can you try using strace, then post the result?

Comment: Nice - It seems, with strace it gets slow enough to not to trigger a race condition -.- It have failed once, when I was dumping to the console instead into a file: http://pastebin.com/S0nTkz5g (or I did not wait long enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, limiting the number of cpu-cores werent enough. I had to use `cpulimit` to decrease the cpu-usage of this program:

Directly after invoking java, I have added this line in the startup script:

`cpulimit -e java -l 25 -b`

This limits java to 25% of the maximum speed of one cpu/ core. Limiting the number of cpus (`-c` option is not necessary). Probably just a race condition in the initialization of the program.